# Texture problems when rendering

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am placing the image on the can using a texture. When rendering, I get the shown image. Some parts with the texture and others without.

How do I make it perfect?

Please help me.

[image],

Comment: It's kind a English language community. So if you can ask in English that would be nice.

Comment: Looks like z-fighting to me...

Comment: Yep my thoughts too. @kathyussk please edit your question and provide more info like material settings, texture nodes, render engine used, object modifiers and geometry. As it stands it ins unclear what could be wrong

Comment: Z-fighting, ovelaping textures or both... When modeling in 3D you cannot have overlapping surfaces. Read this post to understand what that means: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render Instead of duplicating the geometry, map the texture to it. This link should help you understand the process: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39792/how-can-i-apply-textures-without-them-stretching