# UV Distortion Map in Viewport

Tags: uv

Is there a way to display UV distortion **in the Viewport** as a heatmap, like one can do in Modo?
It's NOT a duplicate of [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/is-there-a-way-to-show-distribution-of-uvs-as-a-heat-map), which was about showing distortion not in the Viewport, but in the UV Editor instead.

[image]

Comment: Edited my question -- it's not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Your're right. My bad. I just deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist:

No, unfortunately there is currently no functionality to show the distortion of UV maps in the 3D Viewport as heat maps, like one can do in Modo. The question [Is there a way to show distribution of UVs as a heat map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/is-there-a-way-to-show-distribution-of-uvs-as-a-heat-map) seems to cover all the options for displaying UV stretch in Blender.

But this seems like something that might be possible to code in Python as an add-on, maybe it would not be very difficult to output this information as vertex paint information. Who knows?.. maybe someone will see this question as a fun Python exercise...

Comment: Thank you, Martin!
Well... I wont' give up hope then =D

Comment: You could suggest this feature on [rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) it does not seem like something terribly complicated to implement. Seems like it would be a great addition to new overlays in 2.80. Maybe someone will make it happen. Who knows...

Comment: Maybe if it was added to the Bake list.